# Ruby on Rails: Where to put the .png iphone boomark icon?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, icons, html

I'm trying to add an icon to my rails applications so that the icon shows up on an iphone's homescreen if a user decides to bookmark it.
I have tried a couple of things and its just not working. Where exactly do I have to place the .png file? Do I have to provide multiple sizes in order to support the iphone 4 and the ipad?
To I have to restart the server once I have copied the image over? Do I have to at extra lines of code to one of my views?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone comes along like I did.. this is how you do it on in rails, .erb:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'mb-icon.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon', :type => 'image/png' %>
```

This is the reference I found.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML head place:

```
<link href="http://DOMAIN.COM/iphone-home-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
```

Comment: What's not to get? Put that line in your HTML <head> section and change `http://DOMAIN.COM/iphone-home-icon.png` to be the location of your png?